# Limiting letter spacing role to some characters in input

Tags: css

Is it possible to apply letter spacing to all an `input` but not to the last one?

As you can see from the following example letter spacing is adding to all characters but I need to not apply to the last one.

```css
input{
  letter-spacing:55px;
  padding-left:22px;
}
```

```html
  <input type="text" placeholder="555"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. `letter-spacing` applies to text as a whole unit. It can also be [applied to pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing) such as `::first-letter` and `::first-line`, but as there is no `::last-letter`, it is incapable of giving you the outcome you're looking for.